# How to check if user is signed in into iCloud before saving data

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

Before saving data into CloudKit, how do I check that user has an account and is signed in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `accountStatusWithCompletionHandler` from the `CKContainer` class and check the `accountStatus` returned.

This is described in the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords/CreatingaSchemabySavingRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH3-SW11) documentation.

Here is the Swift version of the example:

```
    CKContainer.defaultContainer().accountStatusWithCompletionHandler { accountStatus, error in
        if accountStatus == .NoAccount {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sign in to iCloud", message: "Sign in to your iCloud account to write records. On the Home screen, launch Settings, tap iCloud, and enter your Apple ID. Turn iCloud Drive on. If you don't have an iCloud account, tap Create a new Apple ID.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            // Code if user has account here...
        }
    }
```